# How to handle InvalidProducerEpochException in Kafka Connect?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I'm using Kafka Connect's JdbcSinkConnector to stream between data stores. Occasionally, I'd get:

```
ERROR [ReplicaManager broker=1] Error processing append operation on partition sink_name-0 (kafka.server.ReplicaManager)
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.InvalidProducerEpochException:
Epoch of producer 72 at offset 2328704 in sink_name-0 is 106, which is smaller than the last seen epoch 107
```

After getting this error, my downstream systems stop receiving updates. I checked the connector's status at http://localhost:8083/connectors/connector_name/status and there's no indication that it failed, the output is:

```
{
  "name":"connector_name",
  "connector":{"state":"RUNNING","worker_id":"connect:8083"},
  "tasks":[{"id":0,"state":"RUNNING","worker_id":"connect:8083"}],
  "type":"sink"
}
```

How am I supposed to detect this issue and recover from it? Is reading from the log the only way?

Also, every time this happens, I need to manually recreate the connectors and the downstream systems. Then, it takes a long time to repopulate all the data. Is there a better way?